# JavaScript & Google Maps - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

I am using Biostall Googlemaps Library for Codeigniter and setting up a map on my HTML view.

In my page header

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ci_bootstrap/assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>

  <?php 
  echo $map['js']; 
  ?>
```

I am trying to do create some custom code for my map and as a test I have been trying to add a simple click event to it outside of the Biostall library

This code is also in the page header

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

     alert("page Loaded");

     $("#map_canvas").click(
        function(){alert("Map Clicked")}
        )

       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'hover', function() {
       alert("Map hovered Over")
       console.log(map)

       });

})
</script>
```

In my HTML view file I have

```
<?php

     echo '<div id="map_canvas">';
      echo $map['html']; 
     echo '</div>';

?>
```

The first alert works on page load

The second alert works on map click

The third alert which is supposed to trigger on hover doesn't work.

I get an error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined"  which relates to "map"

if I understand it correctly I think the issue is caused because the JavaScript for the map  is outputted through `echo $map['js'];`by the library and I am trying to ref the map variable within it using JavaScript. has anyone else come across anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map is NOT created by echoing `$map['js']`, it's created by calling `$this->googlemaps->create_map()` in the controller, storing the results, passing them to the view and echoing them. You might want to take a look at the example:

http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/

Comment: Hi - I have created a map in my view file just as you said but I am trying to add some custom code to it inside <script> tags in my header. I am using the code in my example above but when I run them I get an undefined error in the console which references "map".

Comment: Look at the source of your page and compare it with the source of the example. Do they look the same? Or to be more specific, do you have generated javascript in your page? If not, you should solve that before trying to add custom code. Without the actual code you're using I can't determine where the problem is.

Comment: There is generated javascript n the page - and the map is generated as it should be. Everything works fine with the biostall library. What I am trying to do is create some additional javascript code to do things with the map. To test I just added basic event listeners in my page header and this is the problem I have. When I refresh the page the hover one from my example above gives off - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined - which refers to `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'hover', function() {
       alert("Map hovered Over")
       });`

Comment: Your custom code may be executed before the `map` variable is defined. Try to add it below the Biostall code in the view.

Comment: If you're sure the code with the `var map;` definition is in your source , then my guess is that your javascript is executed before the Biostall code is executed. Not sure why, but try changing `$(function(){` to `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function(){`.

Comment: Sorry deleted previous reply as I seen you asked me to move the custom code down below the Biostall html in the view. I have done that and changed the function to `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function(){` and the undefined error is gone. It now works fine. Thank you for your help :)